# update the session in jquery click function in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I have following long type session on C# server side code

```
long[] grouparray = ..;
Session["grouplist"] = grouparray;
```

I'm getting above Session on ASP.NET View page as follows and try to update the Session as follows when jquery click function happening

```
$("#gpline").click(function () {
    var gplineval = "Value";

    var grouplistvalues = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Session["grouplist"]));
    alert(JSON.stringify(grouplistvalues));

    var found = jQuery.inArray(parseInt(nslineval), grouplistvalues);

    if (found >= 0) {
        // Element was found, remove it.
        grouplistvalues.splice(found, 1);
    }
    else {
        // Element was not found, add it.
        grouplistvalues.push(parseInt(nslineval));
    }        

    alert(JSON.stringify(grouplistvalues));

    // updating the session object 
    @Session["grouplist"] = grouplistvalues

});
```

but this is giving error on firebug console which stating that

> ReferenceError: Session is not defined Session["grouplist"] =
>   grouplistvalues

is this possible to update session on jquery click function ? else how to achieve this

Comment: javascript is a client side technology where as session is server side component. to update it from client side you can have an `ajax` call.

Comment: The session only exists on the server, whereas JS runs on the client. You would need to make an AJAX request to achieve what you need.

Comment: @vijayP oky thnks

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to update session. Try using the below format

```
$.session.set(‘key’, ‘value’);
```

In your case it will be like,

```
$.session.set(‘grouplist’, grouplistvalues);
```

using JquerySession plugin